# add a back slash to string for check url

Tags: android, string, url

I am trying to change the `url(invalid link for 404 error)` to test connectivity and get response to log.
But link shows error:

```
        getCode("https://www.google.com\");
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this url as string ..

```
String s = "http://www.google.com/s";
getCode(s);
```

Comment: String is still not terminated like Anthon said

Comment: Sorry my mistake,thanks for correction so I suggest any non reachable link can be used for it...

Answer (score 3):

You are escaping the closing double quote, so the string is not terminated. Try:

```
   getCode("https://www.google.com\"");
```